# Как запустить сайт wap без web.xml

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, maven

у меня intellij idea и при создании сайта wap не создается web.xml, при запуске через среду разработки сайт работает, но если я хочу залить его на удаленный сервер tomcat apache, сайт не открывается(ошибка 404).
Как мне запустить сайт без web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Используй аннотаций вместо web.xml. Добавь зависимость в вашу сборку (`build.gradle` или `pom.xml`) для Servlet 3.0 API и используй аннотации `@WebServlet`, `@WebFilter` и `@WebListener` в вашем коде вместо конфигурации в web.xml. Или возьми web.xml с миним. набором настроек.